In Flask, is it possible to redirect to a URL fragment?
In Flask, I have main/routes.py using Flask blueprints
from flask import render_template, request
from app.main import bp

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

In templates/base.html, I have
<a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Contact</a>
In templates/index.html, I have
<div id="contact">Contact Us</div>
I'd like to go to #contact and have rendered
mysite.com/#contact
Is this possible? Modify render_template? url_for? Something else?
Thank you for any insight.
I tried href="{{ url_for('main.index', id='#contact') }}" but couldn't see how to proceed.

href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}#contact"

_anchor (str | None) – If given, append this as #anchor to the URL. > url_for('main.index', _anchor='contact')
